# Is there way to bind DataGridView to Dictionary and use Keys as Columns?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

Is there way to bind DataGridView to Dictionary and use Keys as Columns?

for example I have something like a:

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
items.Add("Column 1", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
items.Add("Column 2", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
items.Add("Column 3", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
```

I want to see something like a:

```
[ Column 1] [ Column 2] [ Column 3]
1           1           1
2           2           2
3           3           3
```

I tried to transform simple dictionary to the dynamic object:

```
dynamic itemsData = new ExpandoObject();

IDictionary<string, object> items = (IDictionary<string, object>)itemsData;
items.Add("Column 1", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
items.Add("Column 2", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
items.Add("Column 3", new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

bindingSource1.DataSource = itemsData;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

But there have NO effect and I got as result:

```
[ Key]    [ Value ]
Column 1  System.Collect...
Column 2  System.Collect...
Column 3  System.Collect...
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to add vertical data to an object that thinks horizontally. The general pattern is to add data in rows to a datagrid, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, you can bind dictionary to DataGridView. In order to bind an object to DataGridView's DataSource,That Object should implement IList, ListSource but Dictionary doesn't.

One work around would be converting your dictionary into data table and binding it to DataGridView.

Table column names as Column1, Column2 -----ColumnN and create corresponding number of rows .

Note: Conversion overhead may affect the performance.